# Preventing upcasts for C style array pointers

Tags: c++, casting

```
struct Entry
{
    int Data0;
};

struct ExtendedEntry : public Entry
{
    int Data1;
};
```

I have a simple method expecting a C-style array pointer to Entry like this

```
void Calculate(Entry* data, int count);
```

This method obviously fails, when passing a pointer to an array of ExtendedEntrys. How to prevent users from doing so?

```
ExtendedEntry items[50];
// [...]
Calculate(items, 50);
```

It's not that I pursue a bullet-proof API, I just want to prevent me and my co-workers from making the same mistake again.

Comment: What's the reason for the C style API using C++ structs?

Comment: @tobi303: It fails because `sizeof()` differs, so pointer arithmetic is broken (not polymorphic).

Comment: As for a possible way to solve your problem, why not create an overload that takes a pointer to `ExtendedEntry`? Possibly as a templated function so it will not be defined unless actually called. Then you could use a `static_assert` to cause a compiler error.

Comment: @JohnZwinck yes I already found some article on that. I am just surprised that I was not aware of this. Seems like I managed to stay away from pointers sucessfully for too long

Comment: What about changing the `Calculate` function? Just make it a template and as long as the type passed in has all the appropriate members you can just proceed with the function.

Comment: @John: What would the alternative look like?

Comment: @SirGuy: The calculate method actually takes advantage of a fast memcpy.

Comment: @uebe that's hardly insurmountable.  If you don't trust the compiler to optimize that for you then you can do `if(std::is_pod<T>::value) memcpy(...); else std::copy(...);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make a simple wrapper:

```
template <typename TEntry>
void CalculateSafe(TEntry* data, int count)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(TEntry) == sizeof(Entry), "size mismatch");
    Calculate(data, count);
}
```

This enables passing any derived type so long as it has the same size, which will solve the problem you're having when a C API needs to do pointer arithmetic in an array.

Comment: Perfectly answered!

Answer (score 2):

@John Zwinck's solution is very nice!

Yet, there is an additional approach. You could define the method like this:

```
template < class T >
void Calculate(T * arr, int count)
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<Entry, T>::value, "true");

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        std::cout << arr[i].Data0 << std::endl;
}
```

While the template assures the correctness of the implementation, the static_assert assures that you only call this method with pre-defined types.

Comment: I would argue that the `static_assert` isn't even all that necessary. If someone calls the function with something that doesn't derive from `Entry` but still fulfils all the requirements to make the function compile, what are the odds that it was an accident and should be rejected? Though that is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could declare a deleted overload:

```
template<class T,std::size_t N>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<T,Entry>> 
Calculate(const T(&)[N],int)
  = delete;
```

You could replace type comparison by type size comparison too.